# Why is my confusion matrix "shifted" to the right?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, confusion-matrix

I built a classifier of 4 flower types based on ResNet 50. The accuracy is really high during training, and everything seems good. However, once I plot my confusion matrix, I see that the values are "shifted" to the right instead of in the main diagonal.

What does this mean? Is it a problem with my dataset, or my code?

[image: Confusion Matrix]

Here's what I did to use ResNet 50:

```
def create_model(input_shape, top='flatten'):
    if top not in ('flatten', 'avg', 'max'):
        raise ValueError('unexpected top layer type: %s' % top)

    # connects base model with new "head"
    BottleneckLayer = {
        'flatten': Flatten(),
        'avg': GlobalAvgPooling2D(),
        'max': GlobalMaxPooling2D()
    }[top]

    base = InceptionResNetV2(input_shape=input_shape,
                             include_top=False, 
                             weights='imagenet')

    x = BottleneckLayer(base.output)
    x = Dense(NUM_OF_FLOWERS, activation='linear')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=base.inputs, outputs=x)
    return model

    base = ResNet50(input_shape=input_shape, include_top=False)
    x = Flatten()(base.output)
    x = Dense(NUM_OF_FLOWERS, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=base.inputs, outputs=x)
```

Confusion Matrix Generation:

```
# Predict the values from the validation dataset
Y_pred = model.predict_generator(validation_generator, nb_validation_samples // batch_size+1)
# Convert predictions classes to one hot vectors 
Y_pred_classes = numpy.argmax(Y_pred, axis = 1) 
# Convert validation observations to one hot vectors
Y_true = validation_generator.classes 
# compute the confusion matrix
confusion_mtx = confusion_matrix(Y_true, Y_pred_classes) 
# plot the confusion matrix
plot_confusion_matrix(confusion_mtx, classes = range(4))
```

As requested, this is how I created the generators:

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    color_mode='rgb',
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=True)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    color_mode='rgb',
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=False)
```

Here is an image album of my confusion matrix. Every time I execute model.predict(), the predictions change, always shifting one cell to the right.

[Confusion Matrix Album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3I5l.jpg)

Comment: How could anyone possibly know without your code?

Comment: I'm wondering if this is something that happens commonly. That's why I ask if it could be my code. Just updated adding the model code.

Comment: Could you link to the example on sklearn?

Comment: Two questions: 1) when you say: "the accuracy is really high during training", are referring to the validation set? 2) What's the shape of your validation set?

Comment: Yes, accuracy is ~90% for both train and validation sets. (None, 150,150,3).

Comment: So, I think you should show how you implemented the `validation_generator`. In addition, did you check the values' range of `Y_pred_classes` and `Y_true`? I'm pretty sure it's an issue in the data rather the model

Comment: Just another tip. Print `confusion_mtx` and see how it looks like. It's just to check if it's not a plot issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I imagine it is the code, check your indexing where you create your confusion matrix, it will be off by one

Comment: I added the code I used to generate the confusion matrix, I believe it is not an issue as I took it from the SKLearn website.

Comment: Interesting, take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54973472/confusion-matrix-my-argmax-which-convert-predictions-classes-to-one-hot-vectors

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? The dataset labels must be off by one for the test set surely...

Answer (score 1):

look the `validation_generator` class. when you use `data_generator.flow_from_directory` you need see if param `shuffle` is equal to False like the example above:

```
 val_generator = val_data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        test_data_dir,
        target_size=(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT),
        batch_size=100,
        class_mode="binary",
        classes=['dog','cat'],
        shuffle=False)
```

because the default param is True and the only shuffle the images and not labels.

Comment: It is false :/ I ran into that issue earlier, but I had better results once I used shuffle=False. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem. It can be fixed by reloading the imagedatagenerator right before you do a model.predict.

So:

```
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    color_mode='rgb',
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=False)

Y_pred = model.predict_generator(validation_generator, nb_validation_samples // batch_size+1)
# Convert predictions classes to one hot vectors 
Y_pred_classes = numpy.argmax(Y_pred, axis = 1) 
# Convert validation observations to one hot vectors
Y_true = validation_generator.classes 
# compute the confusion matrix
confusion_mtx = confusion_matrix(Y_true, Y_pred_classes) 
# plot the confusion matrix
plot_confusion_matrix(confusion_mtx, classes = range(4))
```